# cannot write.XStringsViews output

Tags: r, string, dna-sequence

For the following program:

```
library(Biostrings)
library(IRanges) #added this when I saw it mentioned in docs
s1 <- "DNA here" #insert desired sequence between quotes
matchPattern("ATG", s1) # Find all ATGs in the sequence s1
```

I get output that looks like this:

```
  Views on a 3933-letter BString subject
subject: 
CTGCTGGCCCAGCCGGAGCACGCACCG...TGAAACCGCCGTCGGTCGCGGGCGTCG
views:
     start  end width
 [1]    30   32     3 [ATG]
 [2]    63   65     3 [ATG]
 [3]    88   90     3 [ATG]
 [4]   302  304     3 [ATG]
 [5]   327  329     3 [ATG]
 ...   ...  ...   ... ...
[32]  3543 3545     3 [ATG]
[33]  3670 3672     3 [ATG]
[34]  3747 3749     3 [ATG]
[35]  3777 3779     3 [ATG]
[36]  3781 3783     3 [ATG]
```

I want to see all the output, not just the head and tail. I cannot figure out how to write it.

I have tried doing

```
matches <- matchPattern("ATG", s1)
```

and then writing to the screen with 
    write.XStringViews(matches, file="", fasta, width=80)
But I get

```
Error: could not find function "write.XStringViews"
```

The 'matches' variable shows up in my Global Environment, but it shows just the initial numbers, so not a good alternative, unless I can figure out a way to show all of it.

The write.XStringViews code is in the Biostrings documentation, but I cannot make it work. Any ideas on how to view or write the entire output are welcome. Sadly, one page I looked at had `<promise>` next to the write.XStringViews command, so it might not be possible, but if anybody knows how to remove the head and tail restriction on the output.